# Compare 2 double numbers with acceptable error - always shows "not equal"

Tags: c, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, double-precision

**Q:** How can I check if two floating point numbers are equal?

**A:** You can do something like this:

```
#define EPSILON 0.00000001
int compare(double num1, double num2, double error)
{
    if(fabs(num1 - num2) < EPSILON)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**Q:** How can I check if two floating point numbers are equal with some acceptable error? Meaning, I have two numbers, `a = 9.2` and `b = 9.7`. When I set my `error = 0.7` then I can consider `a` and `b` equal. (Its also true for `a = 9.2` and `b = 9.9` but false for `a = 9.2` and `b = 10.0` when the `error` is `0.7`).

**A:** I tried this but every time (no matter how `error` look like), it always shows `0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define EPSILON 0.00000001

static int compare(double num1, double num2, double error)
{
    if((fabs(num1 - num2) < EPSILON - error) || (fabs(num1 - num2 + error) < EPSILON + error))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static int areEqual(const double *x, int size, double error)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        if (!compare(x[i], x[i + 1], error))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    double tab[] = {9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.6, 9.4, 10.0, 9.1, 9.7};
    double error = 0.9;
    const int N = 10;

    printf("%d\n", areEqual(tab, N, error));


    return 0;
}
```

Tried also do it this way:

```
static int compare2(double num1, double num2, double error)
{
    if(fabs(num1 - num2) <= error)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

But shows `0` too.

**EDIT:**

Finally, did it! Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#define EPSILON 0.00000001

static void checkFabs()
{
    printf("%d\n", fabs(-0.7) < 1.0);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(-0.75) < 1.0);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(-0.71) < 1.0);

    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.5) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.6) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.3) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.2) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.8) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.1) < 0.9);
    printf("%d\n", fabs(0.9) <= 0.9);
}

static int compare(double num1, double num2, double error)
{
    if(fabs(num1-num2) <= error + EPSILON)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static int areEqual(const double *x, int size, double error)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        if (!compare(x[i], x[i + 1], error))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    double tab[] = {9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.6, 9.4, 9.9, 9.1, 9.7};
    double error = 0.9;
    const int N = 8;

    printf("%d\n", areEqual(tab, N, error));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isn't it that they are considered equal if fabs(num1-num2)<=error

Comment: @Rob: it should be but I'm getting 0 as well, look: http://ideone.com/m1Sh8i :(

Comment: Using your EPSILON :  fabs(num1-num2)<=error+EPSILON.  However fabs(9.2-9.7) == 0.5 so the first one *will* work (I think passing size=10 is wrong btw)

Comment: @Rob: Please see my edit. Changed it as you suggested but still I'm getting `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: Check if `fabs` is working properly, Use `fabs(-0.7) < 1.0` or something like that.

Comment: @MadHatter: Yes, it works ok. `printf("%d\n", fabs(-0.7) < 1.0);` shows me `1` so its ok.

Comment: @mazix : Fine!! But I will suggest you to compare with few more closer values like `0.75`, `0.71`. This would also help you to get idea of accuracy.

Comment: @MadHatter: All those `printfs`: http://pastie.org/private/uun265xfju9tvuwi5marw show me `1` so its correct. Why it doesnt work in my code?

Comment: Well, `fabs(10.0 - 9.1) > 0.8`. Consider what your `areEqual` code finds, when it reaches the index `i == 5`.

Comment: What is the point of having both `error` and `EPSILON`? If you are trying to compose a total error that is the result of potential errors from two sources, then this may not be the way to do it. In particular, if `EPSILON` is supposed to be some amount of unavoidable error due to the floating-point format, then a fixed value for it is incorrect if the values to be tested will vary significantly in magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 8 elements in your array, not 10. Here is the compare function that you need:

```
static int compare(double num1, double num2, double error)
{
    if(fabs(num1 - num2) < error + EPSILON)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`EPSILON - error` in your code is a negative number!

Just compare it to `error` only.

Comment: It does work. Your function `areEqual` returns zero when 2 number are not equal. 10.0 and 9.1 are more than 0.8 apart...

Comment: When I change `error` to `0.9` the code still shows `0` ... http://ideone.com/t0pNMY

Comment: Your code runs and prints 1 when setting error to 0.9. Try to rebuild.

Comment: Very strange! Take a look: http://s28.postimg.org/5t1xaoh3x/rax2.png. I rebuilded it, but still getting `0`! Why?

Answer (score 1):

don't define epsilon and compare using DBL_EPSILON defined in float.h header.

you have missed the error.

its actually subtracting last value with 0. so its above relative error.

checkout size.

Comment: `DBL_EPSILON` specifies distance between floating-point values (in a certain sense), not the amount of error inherent in floating-point calculations. Likely neither it nor the OP’s `EPSILON` are ideal for whatever it is they are trying to do.